# Javascript default condition in if statement not executing

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write an if statement that prints "input is defined" if the input is defined, otherwise, undefined is printed.

```
function isItUndefined(param) 
{
    console.log(typeof(param))
   if (typeof(param) !== undefined) 
   {
       return 'Input is defined'
   }
   return undefined
}
console.log(isItUndefined(5))
console.log(isItUndefined(null))
console.log(isItUndefined(undefined))
```

The above code however gives the following output, as the default statement does not execute even when the condition is false:

```
number
Input is defined
object
Input is defined
undefined
Input is defined
```

Comment: Use `typeof(param) !== 'undefined'` or `param !== undefined`.

Comment: `typeof(param)` always returns a string, and thus, `!== undefined` is always true.

Answer (score 2):

`typeof` returns a `string`, so your code should be:

```js
if (typeof(param) !== 'undefined') {
  // Print
}
```

MDN actually has a [dedicated page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) on how to detect `undefined` values and what kind of hiccups you might run into with each method. For example, using `typeof` here might actually cause a bug that's relatively easy to catch with a unit test: if you made a typo in `param`, this if statement is going to be `true` almost always.

Answer (score 1):

The [`typeof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) returns a string, so either compare the input directly with the value `undefined`, or compare `typeof param` with the string `'undefined'`.

```js
if (typeof param !== 'undefined') 
// or
if (param !== undefined)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `typeof` to do that

```js
function isItUndefined(param) {
   return param === undefined ? "undefined" : "Input is defined"; 
   // If the goal is to print the return value you may prefer to return a string in both cases, in order to have a consistent return type.
}

console.log(isItUndefined(5))
console.log(isItUndefined(null))
console.log(isItUndefined(undefined))
console.log(isItUndefined())
```